# Promise function delays state variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

How do you correctly store value from a promise function without delay ?

I am trying using a useEffect hook, but still my state is delayed.

It is problematic as if the user is validating his cart, a wrong tax may be applied.

```
useEffect(() => {
SalesTax.getSalesTax(country, region).then((tax) => {
      setTax(tax.rate);
    });
}, [region]);
      

<RegionDropdown
            country={country}
            className="capitalize input"
            value={region}
            onChange={(val) => {
              setRegion(val);
            }}
            required
            countryValueType="short"
            valueType="short"
          />
```

Comment: You don't. `SalesTax.getSalesTax` is asynchronous, and until the promise has fulfilled, *there is no value*. Find a way to indicate that to the user, e.g. by showing a "tax loading" indicator.

Comment: (_An analogy:_) I used to have a similar problem in college.  My girlfriend and I would chat on the phone for hours.  I would ask her to come over, but this was before cellphones, so for obvious reasons, she couldn't leave her dorm room to come see me until we hung up the phone.  There was no way we could see each other unless we ended our conversation.  The moral of this story, in case you missed it, is that you must await (hang up the phone) for the asynchronous thing (going to the other room) to happen before the promise (kissy kissy) can be resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do something like this:

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    SalesTax.getSalesTax(country, region).then((tax) => {
        setTax(tax.rate);
        setLoading(false);
    });
}, [region]);

if (loading) {
    return <p>Loading...<p/>;
}
```

This is a normal way of handling asynchronous actions in React.

Comment: That's what I just tried to implement, but when I try to set cart.taxPrice = tax inside of the promise, my redux won't see any diff, and when I set it outside, I face the same delay.

Comment: So you are using redux, or local state? If redux, you need to dispatch an action, so the reducer can see it.

Comment: Problem solved thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll be using a lot of asynchronous values so how about making a hook such as `useAsync`?

```js
function useAsync(f, [_0, _1, _2, _3, _4]) {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)
  const [result, setResult] = useState(null)
  useEffect(_ => {
    setLoading(true)
    Promise.resolve(f(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4))
      .then(setResult, setError)
      .finally(_ => setLoading(false))
  }, [f, _0, _1, _2, _3, _4])
  return {loading, error, result}
}
```

Now use your hook in your component -

```js
function MyComponent({country, region}) {
  const {loading, error, result} =
    useAsync(SalesTax.getSalesTax, [country, region])
  if (loading)
    return <p>Loading...</p>
  else if (error)
    return <p>Error: {error.message}</p>
  else
    /* result is usable here */
    return <RegionDropdown .../>
}
```

`_0`, `_1`, `_2`, ... are required so ESLint can statically analyze the dependencies. In a future version, perhaps an array can be used. Another option is to disable ESLint for this hook, but note this is [discouraged by Dan Abramov of React](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6880#issuecomment-485912528) -

```js
function useAsync(f, args) {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)
  const [result, setResult] = useState(null)
  useEffect(_ => {
    setLoading(true)
    Promise.resolve(f(...args))
      .then(setResult, setError)
      .finally(_ => setLoading(false))
  },
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  [f, ...args])
  return {loading, error, result}
}
```

Comment: That's not React, that's a linter rule. Which can (and should) be ignored in this case. Or maybe a workaround like `function useAsync(...args) { … useEffect(() => { const f = args.shift(); f(...args) … }, args); }` is accepted by the linter? If all else fails, just avoid accepting arguments directly and require usage like `useAsync(useCallback(() => f(a, b, c), [f, a, b, c]))` instead of `useAsync(f, a, b, c)`.