# Find specific data from object using React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, themoviedb-api

so im using fetch to get an object which has film data, how would i get specific data from that object? I have added an example of one of the object which i am using and I can set thing such as the name, genre, cast, trailers, recommendations etc and then map those but what i'm having trouble with is getting the certification as it an array called results. I have got as far as `release_dates.results` but after that i can't get it to specify 'GB' and then certification.

```
Object
  adult: false
  backdrop_path: "/1Rr5SrvHxMXHu5RjKpaMba8VTzi.jpg"
  belongs_to_collection: {id: 531241, name: 'Spider-Man (Avengers) Collection', poster_path: '/nogV4th2P5QWYvQIMiWHj4CFLU9.jpg', backdrop_path: '/AvnqpRwlEaYNVL6wzC4RN94EdSd.jpg'}
  budget: 200000000
  credits: {cast: Array(59), crew: Array(97)}
  genres: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
  homepage: "https://www.spidermannowayhome.movie"
  id: 634649
  imdb_id: "tt10872600"
  original_language: "en"
  original_title: "Spider-Man: No Way Home"
  overview: "Peter Parker is unmasked and no longer able to separate his normal life from the high-stakes of being a super-hero. When he asks for help from Doctor Strange the stakes become even more dangerous, forcing him to discover what it truly means to be Spider-Man."
  popularity: 7811.558
  poster_path: "/1g0dhYtq4irTY1GPXvft6k4YLjm.jpg"
  production_companies: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
  production_countries: [{…}]
  recommendations: {page: 1, results: Array(21), total_pages: 2, total_results: 40}
  release_date: "2021-12-15"
  release_dates:
    results: Array(35)
    0: {iso_3166_1: 'DE', release_dates: Array(2)}
    1: {iso_3166_1: 'UA', release_dates: Array(1)}
    2: {iso_3166_1: 'SK', release_dates: Array(1)}
    3: {iso_3166_1: 'MX', release_dates: Array(1)}
    4: {iso_3166_1: 'AU', release_dates: Array(1)}
    5: {iso_3166_1: 'TR', release_dates: Array(1)}
    6: {iso_3166_1: 'HU', release_dates: Array(2)}
    7:
      iso_3166_1: "GB"
      release_dates: Array(1)
      0:
      certification: "12A"
      iso_639_1: null
      note: ""
      release_date: "2021-12-15T00:00:00.000Z"
      type: 3
      [[Prototype]]: Object
      length: 1
      [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
      [[Prototype]]: Object
    8: {iso_3166_1: 'IT', release_dates: Array(1)}
    9: {iso_3166_1: 'AR', release_dates: Array(1)}
    10: {iso_3166_1: 'PE', release_dates: Array(1)}
    11: {iso_3166_1: 'NZ', release_dates: Array(1)}
    12: {iso_3166_1: 'IN', release_dates: Array(1)}
    13: {iso_3166_1: 'FI', release_dates: Array(1)}
    14: {iso_3166_1: 'CA', release_dates: Array(1)}
    15: {iso_3166_1: 'RU', release_dates: Array(1)}
    16: {iso_3166_1: 'ES', release_dates: Array(1)}
    17: {iso_3166_1: 'PH', release_dates: Array(1)}
    18: {iso_3166_1: 'PL', release_dates: Array(1)}
    19: {iso_3166_1: 'CZ', release_dates: Array(1)}
    20: {iso_3166_1: 'SG', release_dates: Array(1)}
    21: {iso_3166_1: 'GR', release_dates: Array(1)}
    22: {iso_3166_1: 'TH', release_dates: Array(1)}
    23: {iso_3166_1: 'HK', release_dates: Array(1)}
    24: {iso_3166_1: 'JP', release_dates: Array(1)}
    25: {iso_3166_1: 'IE', release_dates: Array(1)}
    26: {iso_3166_1: 'KR', release_dates: Array(1)}
    27: {iso_3166_1: 'RO', release_dates: Array(1)}
    28: {iso_3166_1: 'BR', release_dates: Array(2)}
    29: {iso_3166_1: 'US', release_dates: Array(2)}
    30: {iso_3166_1: 'TW', release_dates: Array(1)}
    31: {iso_3166_1: 'SE', release_dates: Array(1)}
    32: {iso_3166_1: 'NL', release_dates: Array(1)}
    33: {iso_3166_1: 'FR', release_dates: Array(2)}
    34: {iso_3166_1: 'CH', release_dates: Array(1)}
    length: 35
    [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
    [[Prototype]]: Object
  revenue: 1386428198
  runtime: 148
  spoken_languages: (2) [{…}, {…}]
  status: "Released"
  tagline: "The Multiverse unleashed."
  title: "Spider-Man: No Way Home"
  video: false
  videos: {results: Array(21)}
  vote_average: 8.4
  vote_count: 3610
```

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { useLocation } from 'react-router';
import { Nav} from 'react-bootstrap';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faStar, faPlay, faHeart, faShare} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import {Helmet} from "react-helmet";
import { ScrollCard } from './ScrollCard';

import { Alert } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

export const FilmPage = () => {
    const [details, setDetails] = useState([]);
    const [genres, setGenres] = useState([]);
    const [cast, setCast] = useState([]);
    const [trailer, setTrailer] = useState();
    const [recommendations, setRecommendations] = useState([]);
    const [watch, setWatch] = useState([]);
    const location = useLocation();    

    
    useEffect( () => { 
        fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${location.state}?api_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_TMDB_KEY}&language=en-US&append_to_response=release_dates,videos,credits,recommendations&region=GB`)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
            if (!data.errors) {
                setDetails(data); 
                setGenres(data.genres); 
                setCast(data.credits.cast); 
                setTrailer(data.videos.results[0]?.key)
                setRecommendations(data.recommendations.results)
            }else{
                <Alert variant="danger">Error</Alert>
            }
        })
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    }, [])
    
    useEffect( () => { 
        fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${location.state}/watch/providers?api_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_TMDB_KEY}&language=en-US&region=GB`)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
            if (!data.errors) {
                console.log(data)
                setWatch(data.results.GB.flatrate)
            }else{
                <Alert variant="danger">Error</Alert>
            }
        })
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    }, [])
    

    return (
        <div>
            <Helmet>
                <style>{'body { background-color: black; }'}</style>
            </Helmet>
            <div className='details-container mt' style={{backgroundImage: `url(https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${details.backdrop_path})`}}>
                <div className="details-content">
                    <div className="details-content__poster-container mx-5"> 
                        <img className="poster" 
                            src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/${details.poster_path}`} 
                            alt= {details.title}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="details-content__info">
                        <div className="header mb-1">
                            <h3 className="title">{details.title}</h3>
                            <div className="rating translate-left rounded-pill mx-3">
                                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faStar} className="star"/>
                                {details.vote_average}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {genres && (
                            <div className="genres-container">
                                {genres.slice(0,3).map(genreName => (
                                <p className="genres" key={genreName.id}>
                                    {genreName.name}
                                </p>
                            ))}
                            </div>
                        )}
                        <p className="description">{details.overview}</p>
                        <div className="card-btn">
                            <div className="icons">
                                <a className="details icon-btn mx-2" target="__blank" href={`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${trailer}`}><FontAwesomeIcon className='play' icon={faPlay} /> Trailer</a>
                                <a href className="details icon-btn mx-2"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHeart} /></a>
                                <a href className="details icon-btn  mx-2"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faShare} /> </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className='watch-icons scroller-container'>  
                        <h5>Where To Watch</h5>
                        {watch && (
                            <div className='scroller'>
                                {watch.map(watchProvider => (
                                    <img 
                                        className='watch-icons__logo' 
                                        src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${watchProvider.logo_path}`}
                                        alt= {watchProvider.provider_name}
                                    />
                                ))}
                            </div>
                        )}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className='scroll-container'>
                <h4>Cast</h4>
                {cast && (
                    <div className="scroll-container__content scroller">
                        {cast.slice(0,22).map(castName => (
                            <Nav.Link as={NavLink} exact={true} to={{pathname:`/cast/${castName.id}`, state: castName.id }} className="hidden-link" >                
                            <div className="scroll-container__card" key={castName.id}>
                                <div className="scroll-container__profile">
                                    <img className="scroll-container__img"
                                    src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${castName.profile_path}`}
                                    alt= {castName.name}
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <div className="scroll-container__name">
                                    <h6 className="name">{castName.name}</h6>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                           </Nav.Link>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
            <div className="scroll-container films">
                <h4>Recommended</h4>
                {recommendations && (
                   <div className='scroller' >
                       {recommendations.slice(0,15).map(movieresults => (
                            <ScrollCard movieresults={movieresults} key={movieresults.id}/>
                        ))}
                   </div>       
                )}
            </div>
        </div>

    )
}
```

Comment: I would recommend against use separate `useState` for each field you wish to track. Instead capture the entire API response in a single stateful object. You probably want a way to encode loading and error state as well. See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70522077/633183) for tips on how to make a reusable `useAsync` hook

Comment: how would i do that for mine? could provide an example please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try this

```
let GBdata= (Object?.release_dates?.results.filter(x=>x.iso_3166_1==="GB");
console.log(GBdata);
```

Comment: i changed the let to a use state and that worked for me thank you

Comment: ok, Imad. welcome

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `find` to iterate over all the results in the array and return the 1st result that matches a condition. The shorthand is this:

```
const result = data.release_dates.results.find({iso_3166_1} => iso_3166_1 === 'GB')
```