# Are changes to React component state always executed in call order?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend, state

I have an app that fetches data from the API. There is no safe default value that I can assign to a piece of state, because the API may return *any* value. As a solution, I want to set an element of state to `true` after completing the API call.

```
const [data, setData] = useState<any>()
const [dataLoaded, setDataLoaded] = useState(false)
useEffect(() => {
  setDataLoaded(false)
  Promise.resolve("myData").then(res => {
    setData(res)
    setDataLoaded(true)
  })

  }
}, [])
```

Will the following code, is it *guaranteed* that `dataLoaded` will be set to true only after `data` is populated? I understand that I can't, for example, guarantee myself access the contents of `data` in the call to `setDataLoaded`, but does that mean that the state changes themselves  can execute in any order?

If not, how can I guarantee that it will be?'

I know that this guarantee does exist in class components, but I don't know if it does in hooks, especially if it's happening inside a promise.

Comment: Short answer: yes. React may batch some updates, but won't change their order.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does React keep the order for state updates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48563650/does-react-keep-the-order-for-state-updates)

Comment: @deeBo I did read the answer to that question, but all of the answers and examples are for class components. I couldn't find an equivalent question for hooks, and I don't know what, if anything, has changed.

Comment: Ah, I get you, sorry - and thanks for editing the q. :) I believe what FZs says is true, though I am struggling to find concrete docs to back that up

Comment: One way to definitely get around this is to model your state like this: `const [apiResult, setApiResult] = useState({ dataLoaded: false, data: undefined })` and, after the fetch `setApiResult({ dataLoaded: true, data: res })` - this guarantees you'll have no ordering problems *and* solves the problem in one re-render rather than two :)

Comment: how about writing a custom hook so you don't have to do so much work every time you need an asynchronous value? see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70522077/633183) for a helpful technique.

Comment: React class component, or function component, it's all the same React framework essentially. All React components adhere to the same rules for state and lifecycle.